# Why do I need jquery.min.js vs just jquery.js for script to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress and this has been bugging me for a while. I'm wondering why the code I'm trying to include only works when I include jquery.min.js in 'head' despite the child theme already including jquery.js by default. Let me explain below.

I have a script near the end of my 'body' to specify images in galleries to not have a 'pin it' button show up when hovering over them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tiled-gallery-item a img").attr("nopin","nopin");
});
</script>
```

This code only works (ie., the nopin attribute is added to the relevant img tags) when I include this in the 'head':

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>
```

However, it appears from inspecting source that the child theme already includes jquery.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blog.froy.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blog.froy.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1"></script>
```

Why the heck is the jquery.min.js necessary? I'm new to Wordpress and it's so confusing. I thought the jquery.min.js and jquery.js has no functional difference. What is the jquery-migrate.min.js?

Comment: if your script is added before the jquery script is added then it won't work

Comment: you will have to include your script after jquery is included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress comes with built-in jQuery but doesn't load it by default. it's probably because your theme has been applied `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` inside `functions.php`

One solution for you to replace this default behavior is to add this snippet to your `functions.php`:

```
function modify_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.1');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

Also, because you're using use jQuery version `1.10.2`, [jQuery migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) used here to detect and restore APIs or features that have been deprecated and removed as of version 1.9.

Comment: You. Are. Awesome. Just what I needed to get started. Wish I had more reputation to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Felix provided exactly what was needed. To fully answer my question for future visitors, let me explain in specifics.

Basically, Wordpress includes the jQuery library by default regardless of your theme (I personally use the Genesis framework with a child theme). In addition, Wordpress, by default, sets the library to `noConflict()` mode. This is to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can link.

If you want to include any scripts that require jquery, you need to use the `wp_enqueue_script()`.

*Now this was the important part.* If you don't want to go through the troubles and want to include a simple, quick, script at the end of your `<body>` or elsewhere without having to go into `functions.php` and using enqueue, **replace the `$()` shortcut with `jQuery()`.**

In my case,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tiled-gallery-item a img").attr("nopin","nopin");
});
</script>
```

needed to be...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".tiled-gallery-item a img").attr("nopin","nopin");
});
</script>
```

That's it! I was able to remove the redundant jquery.min.js and simply rely on Wordpress' default jQuery library.

I figured this out by reading [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-22509). You can find more details in those links.

Comment: Changing the default jquery of wordpress is NOT RECOMMENDED.

Comment: Right. Which is why I wanted to find a way to solve my issue - to remove the jquery.min.js and rely on the default WP jquery.

Comment: Thats why i throw an +1 :)